# 521 PROT P required

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, lftp

I am trying to automate file copy from one machine to other(lftp). Following manual commands work

$ lftp
$ set ssl:verify-certificate no
$ connect *ftps://ip*
$ login *username*
$ *it asks for password which i will enter*
$ put test_file.csv
$ bye

Entering all these commands will copy file to the destination folder. But when I am writing all these in .sh file, it throws me `521 PROT P required` error. These is my test.sh file

`lftp -e 'set ssl:verify-certificate no' -u username,'password' ftps://ip << EOF` 
`put test_file.csv`
`bye`

What am i missing here ?

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36135989/14215102

Comment: I tried it this way `lftp -e 'set ftp:ssl-protect-data true' -e 'set ssl:....`*rest same as above*
It did not work